# H2 Database Cluster Recovery

Tags: h2

I have got a SpringMVC application which runs on Apache Tomcat and uses H2 database.
The infrastructure contains two application servers (lets name them A & B) running their own Tomcat Servers. I also have a H2 database clustering in place.

On one system (A) I ran the following command

```
java org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpPort 9101 -tcpAllowOthers -baseDir server1
```

On the other (B) I ran

```
java org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -tcpPort 9101 -tcpAllowOthers -baseDir server2
```

I started the cluster in machine A

```
java org.h2.tools.CreateCluster
-urlSource jdbc:h2:tcp://IpAddrOfA:9101/~/test
-urlTarget jdbc:h2:tcp://IpAddrOfB:9101/~/test
-user sa
-serverList IpAddrOfA:9101,IpAddrOfB:9101
```

When any one of the server is down, it has been mentioned that, one has to delete the database that failed, restart the server and rerun the CreateCluster.

I have the following questions ?

1. If both servers are down, how can I ascertain, which database to
   delete so that I can restart that server and rerun the cluster ?
2. CreateCluster contains a urlSource and urlTarget. Do I need to be
   specific as to give them the same value as was previously given or I
   can interchange them without any side effect ?
3. Do I need to run the CreateCluster command from both the machines?
   If so, do I need to interchange the urlSource and urlTarget ?
4. Is there a way to know whether both, one or none of the servers are
   running ? I want that both IpAddress will be returned if both of
   them are up, one IpAddress if only one is up otherwise none is all
   are down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If both servers are down, how can I ascertain, which database to delete

   The idea of the cluster is that a second database adds redundancy to the system. Let's assume a server fails one every 100 days (hard disk failure, power failure or so). That is 99% availability. This might not be good enough for you, that's why you may want to use a cluster with two servers. That way, even if one of the server fails every 100 days, the chance of both failing at the same time is very very low. Ideally, the risk of failure is completely independent. That would mean the risk of both failing at the exact same time is 1 in 10000 (100 times 100), giving you 99.99% availability. To the risk that both servers are down is exactly what the cluster feature should prevent.
2. CreateCluster contains a urlSource and urlTarget. Do I need to be specific as to give them the same value as was previously

   It depends which one you want to use as the source and which one as the target. The database from the source is copied to the target. The source is that database you want to copy to the target.
3. Do I need to run the CreateCluster command from both the machines?

   No.
4. Is there a way to know whether both, one or none of the servers are running ?

   You could try to open a TCP/IP connection to them, to check if the listener is running. What I usually do is running `telnet <server> <port>` on the command line.